# Filter data for whole numbers (.00)

Tags: r

I'm looking to extract the value of my data frame that are whole numbers, i.e. end in `.00`

```
Price
100.00
100.46
101.00
101.67
```

The resulting data frame would be:

```
Price
100.00
101.00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this could help.

`%%` operator returns the remainder of a division, so `100 %% 1` equals zero and with a `!` mark we can negate it. `!` is Logical Not. In this case it turns zero (`FALSE`) to `TRUE`. Then `filter` returns all those rows where corresponding values of the operation `!(Price %% 1)` equals to `TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!(Price %% 1))

  Price
1   100
2   101
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(Price = c(100, 100.46, 101, 101.67)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Also for more use-cases on `dplyr::filter` check the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html).

Comment: Yep this worked! I'll park as correct once the required time has passed.

Comment: It works. Can you also explain how it works?

Comment: @KathiravanMeeran I added some notes, let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to convert to `integer` and do a `==`

```
subset(df, Price == as.integer(Price))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that efficient but it can also work:

```
dplyr::filter(df, !stringr::str_detect(Price, "\\."))
```

Comment: You could use `negate` argument `dplyr::filter(df, stringr::str_detect(Price, fixed("."), negate = TRUE))`